# Change the color of the SAS window in the taskbar

Tags: colors, sas, taskbar

Hello to all the experts,

I would like to know if it was possible to change the color of the SAS window in the taskbar when the request is finished.
This can be very practical when you have several open SAS windows, rather than clicking on each of them to verify that the request is complete, you will click directly on the correct window.

Here's what it will look like (not on SAS):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUqdV.png)

I know that in older versions of SAS it was possible to do this (probably a default option).

Win 10
Sas Guide 7.1

A big thank you to you,

Comment: What have you tried so far? What kind of research have you done? StackOverflow is used to help developers with their code rather then developing the code for them.

Comment: On Linux Desktop you could post on D-Bus inside your script but on Windows it is possible by calling some DLLs from you script and optaining the Handle of the SAS Window. Get the current process and from a list of all open windows find out which window is the main window of current process then higlight it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

SAS would have to update it's Windows clients (EG 7, EG 8, DMS) to utilize the Windows API classes Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.Taskbar, ProgressBar, and OverlayIcon to communicate the running task(s) progress states.

From a customized perspective a [custom task](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/customtasks/) might be able to be written that would be manipulate the task bar icon of the EG process it is running in.

Or a [task bar manipulating powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565087/how-to-flash-blink-taskbar-icon-in-vb-net) could be invoked from the [System Command example custom task](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/customtasks/).

Other custom task resources: [11 super-useful custom tasks for SAS Enterprise Guide](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2013/11/25/11-custom-tasks/) article includes information about and download links for:

> - SAS Catalog Explorer
> - SAS System Options Viewer
> - Macro Variable Viewer
> - Project Reviewer
> - Task Property Viewer
> - Copy Files to/from SAS Session
> - Message Prompt
> - System Command
> - DATA Step from Data Set
> - Compress SAS Data
> - Calculate Data Cardinalities

Comment: Thank you for all these lines, really very interesting. But it's really too complicated for me and I doubt that I can launch ddl on SAS without authorization.

Have a good day