# Taskbaricon Blinking Effect

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, taskbar

I'm trying to archive the blinking effect as shown in the image with my C# main form. I've Googled a lot and I've seen that it is possible with `System.Windows.Shell` and `TaskbarItemInfo`. This seems much more easy than downloading and importing those `dlls`.

I know how to make a new `TaskbarItemInfo`, but I don't know how I can connect it to the main form.

Any suggestions how I can do this with the `System.Windows.Shell` reference?

Comment: does this SO question/answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73162/how-to-make-the-taskbar-blink-my-application-like-messenger-does-when-a-new-mess   Also you mention an image don't see one in your question.

Comment: Are you talking about reporting *progress* in the taskbar icon? Like the green/yellow/red states?

Comment: @MarkHall Forgot to upload the image. Isn't it possible without importing dlls?

Comment: Judging from your image, yes. In that case, it's simple: `this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.Paused;` See also: http://10rem.net/blog/2009/12/09/overlaying-icons-on-the-windows-7-taskbar-with-wpf-4

Comment: @CodyGray That could also come in handy.

Comment: @CodeGray 'Project' does not contain a definition for 'TaskbarItemInfo' and no extension method 'TaskbarItemInfo' accepting a first argument of type 'Project' could be found

Comment: @Anton is this winforms or Wpf? if winforms look at this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146574/how-do-i-code-a-progress-bar-for-windows-7-to-also-update-itself-on-the-taskbar   You will need to download the the Windows API CodePack. per Wilka's answer

Comment: I've seen that answer before, but the link is dead.

Comment: @Anton It appears to be available though Nuget.    http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Core/  Though in this case it might be easier just to PInvoke like the first link I shared.

Comment: @MarkHall I don't have NuGet, isn't there any zip or installer that I can download?

Comment: @Anton Not that I could find.

Comment: Is looking at the documentation overrated nowadays? [`TaskBarItemInfo` is in the `System.Windows.Shell` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo.aspx). You will need a `using` statement. That really shouldn't be so hard to figure out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window application flash like orange on taskbar when minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309827/window-application-flash-like-orange-on-taskbar-when-minimize)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taskbar notification glow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979534/taskbar-notification-glow)

Answer (score 1):

Cant See the image..are you talking about the windows 7 blinking effect

To make a new TaskbarItemInfo:

public TaskbarItemInfo TaskbarItemInfo { get; set; }

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.TaskbarItemInfo = new TaskbarItemInfo();//
    }
```

But I prefer this:

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FlashWindow(IntPtr Hwnd, bool Revert); 

    // check if window is minimised

    private void Form4_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

         if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)

             FlashWindow(this.Handle, false);

    }
```

This should work..

Also
// Flash window until it recieves focus
FlashWindow.Flash(this);

// Flash window 5 times
FlashWindow.Flash(this, 5);

// Start Flashing "Indefinately"
FlashWindow.Start(this);

// Stop the "Indefinate" Flashing
FlashWindow.Stop(this);

Comment: add explanation to your answer, how it resolve the problem.